# HttpRequest is not reloaded in Observable suscription of Angular 9

Tags: angular, observable, httprequest

In an angular) project I try to relaunch a query every few seconds

```
timer(0, 10000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.dataService.sendGetRequest()))
.subscribe(data => {
  this.result ={
    info: {
      xlabel: 'xvalue',
      ylabel: 'yvalue'
    },
    graph: data
  };
});
```

Observable runs but request is not reloaded

```
public sendGetRequest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER + 'api');
}
```

What could be the mistake?

Uou can review in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5bzdm) where if uncomment constructor app breaks

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: Is `chuckNorris` meant to be set somewhere?

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRandomJoke' of undefined

Comment: I think you forget to inject your service chuckNorris

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5bzdm This is now using a mock observable. Can you describe your problem with this?

Comment: If I try a request in the observable app stops